# WCF binding I not understanding what is wrong

Tags: c#, wcf

I started coding this in vs 2013. I have two endpoints (besides the Mex) - I then wanted to download a lot more data for the last endpoint. So - I added to my config - My own http binding > BHBinding with (sorry for the flaling) 2147483647 everywhere - but my client seams to be getting the old error 65536 not big enough. "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. "

I have not delt with WCF too much - but was able in the past to get it to work, not sure what I am not seeing or understanding. Thanks and Regards.

here is my config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BHBinding" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="FTPServiceLibrary.FTPService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName=""
          contract="FTPServiceLibrary.IFTPError">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="/FTPSettingAddress" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BHBinding" bindingName="" contract="FTPServiceLibrary.IFTPSetting" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/FTPServiceLibrary/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Did you adjust the client's app.config file?

Comment: No, I hoped that update would do the trick for the client side. I guess I would change the client bindingConfiguration?

Comment: Ok, poked around some more - I guess my thoughts on how the client and server fit together needs to change. I did get the wcf connection to work by putting more configuration information that was already in the server config into the client config. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tung to pointing me in the right direction- I will have to now further learn not just about the server side but how server and client have different needs.  Here is my updated client side:

```html
<bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <!--<binding name="BHBinding_IFTPSetting" />-->
              <binding name="BHBinding_IFTPSetting" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
              </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://server.company.com/EI.SecureFTP/FTPServiceLibrary.FTPService.svc/FTPSettingAddress"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BHBinding_IFTPSetting"
                contract="ftpservice.IFTPSetting" name="BHBinding_IFTPSetting" />
        </client>
```